# Make Grails controller action have public access using Spring Security Rest Plugin

Tags: spring, security, grails, authorization

I have a **Grails 3.2.4** app that uses the **Spring Security Core & REST plugins**. My goal is to make certain Grails controller actions available to the public and not locked. By default, the plugin locks down everything ("pessimist lockdown").

If I annotate one of my Grails controller actions using **@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")**, then I have no issues when using the stateful authentication using session (provided by **Core** plugin).

However, that does not seem to work if the controller action is under the **REST** plugin.

What should I do to make a Grails controller action public and not locked if I am using the stateless **REST** plugin? (Authorization header provides the Bearer token).

Comment: I found that "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" was not working because the anonymousAuthenticationFilter was removed using a minus sign in my filterChain.chainMap definitions. So I just removed that "-anonymousAuthenticationFilter" and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` was not working because the `anonymousAuthenticationFilter` was removed using a minus sign in my `filterChain.chainMap` definitions. So I just removed that "-anonymousAuthenticationFilter" and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the filter patterns in your application.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
[pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/error' ,          access: ['permitAll']],

[pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/fonts/**',    access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
```

]